# What is the purpose of specifying captured variable in lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have this code:

```
int i = 0;
[&i](){i++;}();
```

But I can omit i and just use:

```
[&](){i++;}();
```

What is the purpose of specifying `&i`? (and similarly `=var` and `=`). Is it affecting compile time or runtime performance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`&i` means only `i` is captured as reference, while `&` means all variables which are used in the lambda, are captured from the scope.

```
int i = 0, j = 10;

[&i]{ i++; j++;}(); //error: j is not captured by reference

[&]{ i++; j++;}(); //ok: both variables are captured by reference
```

The `&i` approach is provided by the language to *limit* the amount of captured variables. C++ provides you full control on the captured variables, as to which *specific* variables to capture, how to capture (by value, or reference).

Same reasoning with `i` and `=`:

```
int i = 0, j = 10;

[i]{ i++; j++;}(); //error: j is not captured (only i is captured by value)

[=]{ i++; j++;}(); //ok: both variables are captured by value

//more
[&i, j]{ i++; j++;}(); //ok: captured i by reference, j by value
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes my question is not about the difference of them, which I am aware of already. I want to know why the first one is provided if the second one captures all already

Comment: @texasbruce See my answer for *why* the syntax is available.

Comment: Only capture-default uses `=`, normal by-copy captures use just the name.

Comment: @Xeo: I didn't understand your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: You have `[=i]` and `[..., =j]` for by-copy captures, but that's ill-formed - only `[i]` and `[..., j]` is allowed / needed. `[=]` is only used to specify "by-copy" as the capture-default.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh you're right. I'm wondering no one caught this silly mistake. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes you may want to capture different variables in different ways:

```
std::vector<int> v { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
int n = 3;

//Capture v by reference and n by value:
auto getNth = [&v, n](){ return v[n]; };

//Behavior:
n = 9999;
getNth(); //returns 10 - changing n didn't affect the lambda
v[3] = 42;
getNth(); //returns 42 - changing v did affect the lambda
```

This is why the more-detailed syntax is available.

Answer (score 18):

This feature isn't about performance it's about readability and maintainability.  When you use the blanket capture syntax `[&]` or `[=]` then it obscures the state which is shared between the original method and the lambda body.  This can contribute to maintenance issues in a method if a dev incorrectly assumes a value isn't captured and it is.  Having a capture clause makes it much more explicit what state the lambda relies on.

Answer (score 11):

> What is the purpose of specifying &i? (and similarly =var and =). Is it affecting compile time or runtime performance?

You can specify whether values are captured by reference or by value.  Using `[&]` specifies that you want to capture everything by reference, but you can also write lambda which does:

```
[=, &i, &j]()
```

Which says capture everything by value, *except* capture `i` and `j` by reference.

In your specific case, this isn't useful - you can just say capture everything by reference, and the compiler will determine that you're using `i`, and capture it by reference - but when you deal with multiple variables being captured, C++ allows you to control how each is captured individually.

Answer (score 4):

If you list the variables to capture, you're being explicit in what you want. And you get a compiler error in case you use something you didn't want to (you didn't capture it). This may be a good thing (you made a genuine mistake in the implementation) or a bad thing (you just forgot to list the variable).

It really depends on the particular scenario. I'd that the more complex the lambda and/or the more complex the containing scope, the better it is to be explicit about what you capture.

There's an extra point, and that is mixing capture by value and capture by reference - you have to be explicit in at least one of those. Example:

```
int i, j, k;

auto f = [=, &i]() { /* code which can read i, j and k but can only modify i */ };
```